# Google VM with 4 vCPUs, 30 GB, Ubuntu18.04 memory running extremely slow with Magento 2 how to fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, magento, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, magento2

I'm developing a Magento 2.3 website in a Google Cloud VM(4 vCPUs, 30 GB memory), working with Ubuntu 18.04.

The database is located in another server, so as not to compromise the Magento server.

However, the website is far too slow.

I've already tried to set Magento as production mode, but it's still slow.

I'm not sure if the problem is Magento, or the server config.

What else can I try to make the website faster?

Comment: this would be better suited for https://serverfault.com

Comment: I'll do it as well, is just that I'm not sure if the problem is with magento or the server.
Thank you anyway